# Efficient way to organize your collectible Actors

Tags: c++, unreal, blueprints

Assuming I want to make a RPG, where I can pick up different stuff, like plants and weapons.

How would you create the Actors?

More precisely:

Would you create an Actor for every item, maybe deriving from a super class called "collectible"? Or would you rather just use one Actor, "collectible", where you can set the Mesh and Meta-Infos (for Inventories for example) in the Instances placed in the Editor? Or maybe even a class "collectible" which reads information from a different text-file-format, where you also choose the file directly for every Instance?

Does it matter? Is it just personal style preference?

What (in general, of course it varies depending on the implementation) is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the flexibility versus speed required.

A fixed single object is faster but larger in terms of memory and rigidness.

The larger memory footprint is as compared to a small number of loaded sub-classes, which depends on the use case.

Sub-classing allows more flexibility through dynamic resolution, but is slower.

There is no best answer for every scenario.

Usually personal preference takes over, but careful analysis provides better results in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

What is collectible from data perspective (30 rounds of .45 ACP) should be separated from what is the collectible object that's actually in the world (actor with glowing and rotating magazine mesh, collision box, etc) and the communication to the player should be handled by some sort of message.

Therefore, I could add something to the player inventory by a simple message from anywhere - could be a proximity thing, could be story trigger, could be a simple collectible ...

And for the collectible, I'd have an Actor with the possibility to modify it's mesh, name, etc. for simple stuff (say floating blobbing coin, or ammo, or...). For some hero item, or whatever I'd be free to have a custom special actor since the only limiting part would be sending the message.